# For loop for dropping a string pattern from a column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to drop '_Adj' from a column name, in a 'df_merged' data frame if (1) a column name contains 'eTIV' or "eTIV1'.

```
for col in df_merged.columns:
    if 'eTIV1' in col or 'eTIV' in col:
        df_merged.columns.str.replace('_Adj', '')
```

This code seems to be producing the following error:

KeyError: '[] not found in axis'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options:

**Option 1**

```
df_merged.columns = [col.replace('_Adj','') if 'eTIV' in col else col for col in list(df_merged.columns)]
```

**Option 2**

```
df_merged = df_merged.rename(columns={col: col.replace('_Adj','') if 'eTIV' in col else col for col in df_merged.columns})
```

Comment: this works great. thank you. I modified by adding an "or statement (I think this should be the right format): df_merged.columns = [col.replace('_Adj','') if 'eTIV' in col or 'EstimatedTotalIntraCranialVol' in col else col for col in list(df_merged.columns)]

Comment: You bet, I excluded the `eTIV1` condition check since it will be captured by the `eTIV` condition.

Comment: Is option 1 or 2 more elegant from your perspective?

Comment: IMO, Option 1 is the most readable, whereas Option 2 is likely the most Pythonic. It avoids recasting the columns as a list for the list comprehension in Option 1.